# Convert data in square brackets to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

im currently working with React and MQTT.js and I receive data in the following format as a string:

```
[Message1: 0, Message2: 0, Message3: 0]
```

The problem is, that I need the data in JSON-format. The data should look like this:

```
{"Message1": 0, "Message2": 0, "Message3": 0}
```

Does anybody now, how I can do it? Would be awesome!

Comment: The `JSON.parse` is one option. Furthermore, you can provide a custom serializer function to that.

Comment: @Artem `[Message1: 0, Message2: 0, Message3: 0]` is not valid json, how would you parse then

Comment: I already use JSON.parse but I need to replace the square brackets, add the quotes and so on

Comment: Is `[Message1: 0, Message2: 0, Message3: 0]` a string?

Comment: @Artem The reviver function passed to `JSON.parse` is called after the parse is complete.

Comment: Any idea on the name of the first format? Nothing we can provide can be relied upon based on just that fragment of code. Best use a dedicated parser.

Comment: @sln i can't find any documentation about that string, can you please add the code that is returning you that string?

Comment: @MadhuMagar yes

Comment: @Berto99 unfortunately not atm because Im only working on the receiving component and somebody else is testing it

Comment: @sln an you can't access the method that is returning that string?...

Comment: We can provide code that will alter that specific string so that it works using `JSON.parse`, but then you'll be asking another question when that service responds with some other crazy format. The best thing is to talk to the provider of that service and get documentation on what the expected format is for all messages you expect to receive, and write custom parsers for them, or convince them to use JSON, which has been a standard format for passing data between systems for many years.

Comment: @MadhuMagar Comments are not for sharing code. If you have an answer to the question, write an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = "[Message1: 0, Message2: 0, Message3: 0]";
var stringArray = str.replace("[", "").replace("]","").split(",")
var result = stringArray.map(function(strObj) {
    const [key, value] = strObj.split(":")
    return {
        [key]: value
     };
})
```